# Cycles GPU CUDA out of memory - How to identify the problem objects?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

Rendering a large environment scene (also with multiple smoke and physics simulations) in Blender causes my GTX 980ti to run out of CUDA memory. (I've baked all the simulations but am unsure if this makes a difference to memory in rendering)

Is there a way to identify which particular objects / materials / textures / simulations are using up the most amount of memory?

Comment: How large are your texture and how many are you using?

Comment: read this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/61421/1853

Comment: try breaking the scene into layers/passes : https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing/

Comment: Thanks cegaton, will give those links a look, there's a lot of textures from imported models and some I've made myself so I'll have to look closer at the textures... just was curious if there may be some way to identify which objects are hogging the memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no automated tool to identify the resource hogs in your scene. You'll need to do most of it manually. But surely you'll have an idea on what object / element could be the cause? Like, high res textures, dense meshes (check subsurf and multires modifier render settings too!!), lots of copies instead of instances, or fur / hair.

One possibility is to put those objects on separate layers, and render just that layer with very low samples (1 should be enough). The memory consumption can then be read in the debug print line on top of the render view.

Important: Use final render (<kbd>F12</kbd>), as many modifiers (like the Subsurf by default) have higher settings for final render than for vieport render.

[image: peak memory usage]

### Edit

For rendering animations, it might also be beneficial for debugging this to have the memory usage in the test render frames directly. You can enable **Stamp Output** and check **Memory** to do so, **if you have Blender 2.78 (or a current development build which was compiled after Jul 14, 2016)**:

[image: peak mem stamp]

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I've not done a large scene like this before but have been importing lots of different models and appending different elements (such as grass essentials) plus have multiple smoke and physics simulations running, so am not sure which is effecting memory the most (hence the question). Wasn't sure if there was just an easier way to identify memory usage of objects, but will try putting them on separate layers and checking all the textures.

Comment: I just realised that for some reason I don't have the 'Memory' checkbox available in the Metadata dropdown? How do you enable this?

Comment: @aliasguru what version are you using? I don't see the option for Memory in the metadata section.

Comment: @Dan I'm using a development build of the upcoming 2.78 release. As far as I can track it down, they implemented this mid of July, but even when checking the preliminary release notes, they forgot to add information about this feature.

Answer (score 1):

> put those objects on separate layers, and render just that layer with very low samples (1 should be enough). The memory consumption can then be read in the debug print line on top of the render view. Important: Use final render (F12), as many modifiers (like the Subsurf by default) have higher settings for final render than for vieport render.

This method was helpful, I identified some large memory objects and found some larger than needed textures, lowered the image size of these and lowered some subsurface modifiers from background objects (such as rocks) and now have it rendering on the GPU! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A hugely overlooked feature is the simplify section in the scene panel.  Too many subdivisions globally can cause memory crashes and it can be hard to find where the highly subdivided objects are in scenes with several objects.  Make sure the render section is set to no more than 2 or 3 subdivisions.  For most purposes, this should suffice and prevent memory errors.