# CUDA Error: Out of Memory in cuArrayCreate(&handle, &desc)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, error

```
CUDA Error: Out of Memory in cuArrayCreate(&handle, &desc)
```

I get this error when rendering with Cycles on my GPU. I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with this... My scene DOES have some very high-res textures (up to 10K) and most of the textures also have a map for Gloss, Reflection, Normals, and displacement. My specs are as follows:

> CPU: Intel i5-4460
>
> GPU: Geforce GTX 1060 6GB VRAM
>
> RAM: 8GB

Comment: Cuda is out of memory, means your scene is too complex for the available memory

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos would reducing the resolution of most of the textures used append this? Or is it because of the geometry? I've handled much more complex geometry in scenes before...

Comment: Basically your scene exceeds the resources of your GPU. Texture size should not be larger than that of the size they will be in the final render. For example if you have an object in the distance that has a texture of 4k but will only be 100 pixels on the screen, you are just wasting resources. Only the textures that will be seeing in great detail and occupying a large portion of the screen in the final render should require   large size textures. 3D rendering is all about optimizing  resources to get acceptable results, use every trick that you can think of to avoid overtaxing your system.

Comment: Think also that if your GPU is the only graphics card on your system, the resources are shared with the monitor(s). So not all of the vRAM is available for rendering

Comment: @cegaton I was not aware that when GPU rendering your textures are flushed to VRAM, Not RAM. And I was wasting resources, like you said. Could you put your response in answer format so I can accept it?

Comment: @cegaton I just checked and the sum total of all my textures including normal maps etc. is ~700mb. Does Blender inflate texture data or something when it is moved to VRAM for render? If not, what is all the other VRAM space used for?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61508/cycles-gpu-cuda-out-of-memory-how-to-identify-the-problem-objects